# X Position of a Variable Becoming Negative

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I'm having a problem in my code where the initial x and y values (gx and gy) start out as positive, then jump to negative at around the third loop (specifically to coordinates (-8, 12)), then continue on as normal. I've checked multiple times, and there is only one thing that changes the variables. However, it doesn't set them to a negative number. Why does it keep going to that particular point?

Edit: To clarify, the fact that gx and gy become negative isn't the issue so much as the fact that they jump to (-8, 12) after being at (355, 350) for two loops. I'm unclear on why this happens, and have not been able to troubleshoot it yet. Any ideas why it goes to that point?

Also, it may be worth noting that I'm using a web editor called p5.js.

Here is my code:

```
var ris = 0;
var hyp = 0;
var gx = 355;
var gy = 350;
var count = 1;
var rem = 0
var dir = 0
var xdir = 1
var ydir = 1
var cx = 0
var cy = 0
var xpos = 200;
var ypos = 200;
var moveHoriz = 0;
var moveVert = 0;

function gmove(){
  if (gx == xpos){
    cx = 1
  } else if(gy == ypos){
    cy = 1      
  }
  if (cx == 1 && cy == 1){
    console.log("this functions");
    if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) < 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) == 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = 1
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) < 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) > 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = -1
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) == 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) > 0){
    xdir = 1
    ydir = -1
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) > 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) > 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = -1
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) > 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) > 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = 1
    print("yeeeee")
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) > 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) < 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = -1
    print("yeeeeee")
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) == 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) < 0){
    xdir = 1
    ydir = -1
    print("yeeeeeee")
  } else if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) < 0 && (400-gy)-(400-ypos) < 0){
    xdir = -1
    ydir = -1
    print("yeeeeeeee")
    }
  } else {
  ellipse(gx, gy, 20, 20);
  ris = (ypos-gy);
  run = (xpos-gx);
  hyp = pow(ris, 2) + pow(run, 2);
  hyp = sqrt(hyp);
  stroke(0);
  line(gx, gy, xpos, ypos);
  console.log(xpos+10, ypos+10, gx-10, gy+10);
  hyp = hyp/(100*hyp);
  if ((400 - gx)-(400-xpos) > -30 && (400-gx)-(400-xpos) < 30 && (400-ypos)-(400-gy) > -30 && (400-ypos)-(400-gy) < 30){
    if(count == 1){
      rem = round(gx/400);
      count = count + 1;
    }
  } else {
    if(count == 1){
      rem = round(gx/400);
      count = count + 1;
    } else {
      gx = xdir*(rem*count);
      console.log("math:", ydir*(rem*count))
      gy = ydir*(rem*count);
      count = count + 1;
      ellipse(gx, gy, 20, 20);
      console.log(count);
    }
    }
  cx = 0;
  cy = 0;
   }
}

function setup() {
  //this part isn't relevant either
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  print(gx, gy);
}

//this is a forever loop
function draw() {
  background(255);
  gmove();
  ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
  }
}

//everything below this point is also irrelevant; it just makes an ellipse move with wasd
function keyPressed(){
  if (key == "a") {
    moveHoriz = -1;
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
    }
    if (key == "d") {
      moveHoriz = 1;
      ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
    }
    if (key == "w"){
      moveVert = -1;
      ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
    }
    if (key == "s"){
      moveVert = 1;
      ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
    }
}
function keyReleased(){
  if (key == "d") {
      moveHoriz = 0;
    }
    if (key == "a") {
      moveHoriz = 0;
    }
    if (key == "s"){
      moveVert = 0;
    }
    if (key == "w"){
      moveVert = 0;
    }
}
```

Apologies for the length, and thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: `gx = xdir*(rem*count)` When `xdir` is negative, this will be negative.

Comment: Or `xdir` could also be negative sometimes, and thus on multiplication, the computed value will be negative assigned to `gx`.

Comment: I tried those, but I don't think that's the issue. Sorry; I should have made it more clear initially that the problem is the seemingly random jump from (355, 350) to (-8, 12) on the third loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: fixed now! Not sure what the issue was, but I changed the code to use trig for movement, and it fixed the problem. Thank you, though!